# Parsing a web page with Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, html, parsing, html-agility-pack, windows-phone-8.1

Is HtmlAgilityPack the only choice for parsing a web page in WP 8.1 or is there something better? Is there an example somewhere? Thank you.

Comment: What is exactly that you are trying to achieve? In my situation I always tend to use my own methods and classes for basic HTML.

Comment: I'm just asking what i can use to parse an html page using WP8.1 since HtmlAgilityPack doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @AsAs I am using the NuGet package HtmlAgilityPack-PCL in a PCL, which should mean that it is usable in WP8.1 apps

Answer (score 1):

I'm not  sure if this libraries can be used on WP 8.1 (but all are written  in c# and I think you should  be  able  to recompile them  for  WP 8.1 )    you  have to give  them  a try  yourself:

1. [arachnode.net](http://arachnode.net/*)
2. [sharp-query](https://code.google.com/p/sharp-query/)
3. [NCrawler](http://ncrawler.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20Started&referringTitle=Documentation)